# Future date or day after 160 days excluding saturday sunday

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I want a SQL or PHP Query which deactivates an account after six months.

The simple solution is

```
Select datediff(curdate(),last_date) as diff
```

I entered in complex situation where I have to exclude Saturday & Sunday.

I am stuck at the future date or day where I have to make a record's status = 0

The answers I found here are based on two dates or range of dates 
but I have to calculate the second date.

Comment: Please include some of what you have already tried. How far did you get with excluding those days so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly sure there must be a more efficient way than this, but worth a try (using NOW() as the start date):-

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 7
            THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 2 DAY)) = 7
                        THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 4 DAY)
                    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 2 DAY)) = 1
                        THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 3 DAY)
                    ELSE 
                        DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 2 DAY)
                END
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 1
            THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 1 DAY)) = 7
                        THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 3 DAY)
                    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 1 DAY)) = 1
                        THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 2 DAY)
                    ELSE 
                        DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 1 DAY)
                END
        ELSE
            CASE 
                WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) DAY)) = 7
                    THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 2 DAY)
                WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) DAY)) = 1
                    THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) + 1 DAY)
                ELSE 
                    DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (160 DIV 5) * 7 + (160 % 5) DAY)
            END

    END
```

It takes the number of days and divides by 5 to get the number of weeks, and mods by 5 to get the number of extra days. If the start date is a Saturday it adds 2 days, if a Sunday it adds 1 day, then adds 7 times the number of weeks plus the extra days. Then if the resulting day is a Saturday it adds 2 further days, if a Sunday it adds 1 further day.

Or for a somewhat odd way of doing it:-

```
SELECT MAX(EndDate)
FROM
(
    SELECT @StartDate:=DATE_ADD(@StartDate, INTERVAL CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(@StartDate) = 6 THEN 3 WHEN DAYOFWEEK(@StartDate) = 7 THEN 3 WHEN DAYOFWEEK(@StartDate) = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END DAY) AS EndDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100 AS daysAdd
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
        (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens,
        (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) hundreds
        HAVING daysAdd < 160
    ) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT @aCnt:=0, @StartDate:=DATE(NOW())
    ) sub2
) Sub0
```